# Changes are not tracked when using projections in Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

With projections (0 changes):

```
var changesBefore = Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<OrderLocationEntity>().ToList(); //before change - 0

var orderLocation = Db.OrderLocation.AsTracking().Select(ol => new OrderLocationEntity
{
    Id = ol.Id,
    Address = ol.Address,
    City = ol.City,
    Created = ol.Created,
    OrderId = ol.OrderId,
    Zip = ol.Zip
}).First();

orderLocation.Address = "address";

var changesAfter = Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<OrderLocationEntity>().ToList(); //after change - 0
```

Without projections (1 changes)

```
var changesBefore = Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<OrderLocationEntity>().ToList(); //before change - 0

var orderLocation = Db.OrderLocation.AsTracking().First();

orderLocation.Address = "address";

var changesAfter = Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<OrderLocationEntity>().ToList(); //after change - 1
```

**Setup**

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.1

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.1.1

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OrderDatabaseContext>()
                .UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:")
                .Options;
```

> If the result set contains entity types coming out from LINQ composition, EF Core will track them.

**Source**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

**Why are changes not being tracked when using projections?**

Comment: *"Why are changes not being tracked when using projections?*" Because EF Core designers made it this way. Why you are projecting to the same entity type? To skip retrieving some properties? Well, most likely that's why they are not tracked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice "entity types":

> If the result set contains **entity types** coming out from LINQ
>   composition, EF Core will track them.

From the same docs:

> If the result set **doesn't contain any entity types**, then no tracking
>   is done.

Your projection doesn't contain entity types, so changes will not be tracked.

For example if you will introduce property to keep `OrderLocationEntity` instance, that instance will be tracked by the context

```
var location = Db.OrderLocation.AsTracking()
    .Select(ol => new OrderLocationEntity
    {
        Id = ol.Id,
        Address = ol.Address,
        City = ol.City,
        Created = ol.Created,
        OrderId = ol.OrderId,
        Zip = ol.Zip,
        Location = ol // entity instance passed to the projected object
    })
    .First();

location.Location.Address = "New Address"; 

Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<OrderLocationEntity>().ToList(); //after change - 1
```

Comment: I dont... understand. Why would they enable tracking for child properties and not the "base" object, in this case "new OrderLocationEntity"? Because OrderLocationEntity is Db.OrderLocation.

Comment: Because `new OrderLocationEntity` is a new instance and not created by the actual "query"

Answer (score 1):

Because they do not track them. This was disabled in 3.1 where projects automatically add AsNoTracking.

One more of many many many decisions that can not really be explained and make EfCore 3.1 a product - that can not compete with Ef 6.4.

Comment: Shouldn't "AsTracking" override that default setting then?

Comment: Hardly? Not sure. Point is that there is no tracking of changes for projected entities to start with as there is no update mechanism for them. Projection works in only one direction.

Comment: But EF6 does not allow projecting to entity types at all, isn't it? So EF Core is actually better in that regard. And projected entities were never tracked, so this is not new behavior either.